# Unicode characters not getting displayed in csv export using c#

Tags: c#, csv, unicode, unicode-string

following code is working fine if i put only string as input

```
Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
            Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=WaitingForApproval_" + ".csv");

            String output = "";
            output += "Name, callNumber" + "\n";
            output += "잘 지냈어요?,34343555" + "\n";
            Response.Write(output);
            Response.End();


            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(new FileStream("c:/Temp.csv", FileMode.Create), Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                sw.WriteLine(_exportedCSV);
            }
```

But when I try to generate string from code it is not working for me after export csv it shows wrong character instead original-

```
    string dataCSV = GenerateCSV();

  using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(new FileStream("c:/Temp.csv", FileMode.Create), Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                sw.WriteLine(dataCSV);
            }


public string GenerateCSV()
{

 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            string Value = string.Empty;
            sb.Append("sep=;");
            sb.Append("\r\n");

// some logic to get string

  return Convert.ToString(sb);

}
```

actual string I get from above code in debug mode -

```
sep=; Country;Korea;Name;잘 지냈어요?(HWR);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6JrG.jpg)

Comment: I think You should set your string builder in GenerateCSV function to work with UTF-8 too

Comment: Does the second example include `Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8` ?

Comment: @Evenhuis: Yes, it is included.

Comment: "it shows wrong character" - When seen in what? Opened in what program?

Answer (score 0):

try to do following inside `GenerateCSV` for `StringBuilder`

```
 Encoding.Convert(Encoding.Default, Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.Default.GetBytes(mystring));
```

more specific return like -

```
  return Encoding.Convert(Encoding.Default, Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.Default.GetBytes(sb));
```